# StackTrace for WebTransaction using OpenTelemetry Java Agent

Tags: java, spring, agent, open-telemetry, apm

I am trying to figure out if the OpenTelemetry agent is capable of capturing the complete stack trace for a WebTransaction.
(Eg:  Controller.method1  --> Service1.method2 --> Service2.method3 --> Repository.method1 )

Tried multiple configuration, but not getting the intermediate Service methods in the trace in Jaeger.    (My exporter is Jaeger right now)

Is this even possible with this agent (auto instrumentation), without any app code changes?

Any configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a span for each Java method, I'd recommend to look into profiling solutions - it's not possible with javaagent.

If you're fine with adding annotations to every method that you're interested, have a look at https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/automatic/annotations/